# What was the space helmet "vomit port"?

Tags: apollo-program, spacesuits, space-sickness

> Based upon centrifuge test results, MSC directed Hamilton Standard to modify the space suit helmet.  **The vomitus port** and other obstructions to the line of sight in the downward direction were deleted.
>
> *The Apollo Spacecraft: A Chronology*, [December 29 1963 - January 4 1964](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4009/v2p2b.htm#63dec)

**What was this vomit port?**  How was it supposed to work?  Are there pictures (of the port, not the vomit)?

Comment: The vomit port: aka the fun port! I wonder if it was an acronym for something? Vacate Ones Meal In Time maybe?

Comment: Consdering the near-disasters that have happened when excess perspiration (in zero-g) flowed towards the mouth and nose, I guess that vomiting in zero-g would lead to a similar self-strangulation issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the device in question is described in US Patent 3,437,165 "VENTING DEVICE FOR PRESSURIZED SPACE SUIT HELMET" (filed Feb 27, 1967). It is possible that NASA did not file immediately for patent, especially when the port was eliminated. Hamilton Standard is listed as government employee on the patent form.

The patent can be found in NTRS under the following link:

- [PDF] https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710016857/downloads/19710016857.pdf
  ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210311093950/https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710016857/downloads/19710016857.pdf))

The apparatus is described as

> A venting device comprising a fixture mounted in the faceplate of a crewman's helmet for use with a pressurized space suit, wherein the device incorporates valve means providing controlled venting of the helmet in the oral-nasal area and incorporating a collapsible duct or funnel positionable between a collapsed stowed condition adjacent the faceplate and an operating position in which it projects into abutment with the mouth of the crewman
> for elimination of vomitus expelled by the crewman.

Illustration of the port:

[image: Vomitus Port Illustration]

The aforementioned PDF contains some more close-ups and technical drawings of the inner workings of the mechanism.